# Joining table with its own and select a row in Sql

Tags: sql, select, join, row

I have a table called 'calls', 
columns are:

```
a_imei_number (imei of caller)
b_imei_number (imei of number which is called)
a_phone_number (number of caller)
b_phone_number (number of number which is called)
call_start_time (as hour)
call_end_time (as hour)
call_day (as day)
```

I am trying to find calls whic has cloned Imei numbers so at intersected time there must be at least 2 row so phone_numbers must be different and imei_numbers are same. like

```
id   a_imei  b_imei  a_phone   b_phone   call_start_time  call_end_time  call_day 
1    A       b       123       321        13:30            13:50          01.02.2014
2    A       c       999       888        13:41            13:55          01.02.2014
```

how can i join that table in its own ?

note: a_imei of a row may be same with b_imei of other row, because maybe one cloned phone is calling and clone of that phone is called by someone.

Comment: to join cant you just do soemthing like... `FROM calls a, calls b WHERE a.column=b.column`?

Comment: no i cant that is why i asked the question

Comment: Can you show us some sample data from the table, and what you would expect the select to select from your sample data and what not to select? At first glance, I do not know why you can't just do what I suggested above.

Comment: the data in the table just like in the question. but i cannot write select to find rows whose times are intersects. call_start_time of one of it will be between start and end time of other one while imei numbers are same but different rows

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: oracle. you can suggest pl/sql solution too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get all of the `a_imei` clones:

```
SELECT  c1.*
FROM    calls As c1
JOIN    calls As c2
    ON  c1.a_imei           =   c2.a_imei
    AND c1.a_phone          !=  c2.a_phone
    AND c1.call_start_time  <   c2.call_end_time
    AND c1.call_end_time    >   c2.call_start_time
ORDER BY c1.a_imei, c1.call_start_time, c1.call_end_time
```

---

Here's how to compare both the "a"s and "b"s together:

```
SELECT  c1.*, c2.*
FROM    calls As c1
JOIN    calls As c2
    ON  c1.call_start_time < c2.call_end_time
    AND c1.call_end_time   > c2.call_start_time
    AND (   (c1.a_imei     = c2.a_imei AND c1.a_phone != c2.a_phone)
        OR  (c1.a_imei     = c2.b_imei AND c1.a_phone != c2.b_phone)
        OR  (c1.b_imei     = c2.a_imei AND c1.b_phone != c2.a_phone)
        OR  (c1.b_imei     = c2.b_imei AND c1.b_phone != c2.b_phone)
        )
ORDER BY c1.a_imei, c1.call_start_time, c1.call_end_time, c1.b_imei
```

Comment: a and b must be in same query, because a_imei and b_imei also can intersect for example you and i use same imei(cloned-illegal) you called someone so your imei in a_imei and at the same time someone called me and my imei in b_imei column-we would be used phones whose imei's are same and at the same time with different phone numbers.

Comment: I would make a small suggestion that the phone of the first is less than the second, so it does not do the inverse and return the same set of rows for the phoneA + phoneB pair and phoneB + phoneA pair...